# UITableView drag and drop cell to bottom of list below last cell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, drag-and-drop

I haven't found anything on this particular issue. I would like to be able to drag and drop a UITableViewCell to the bottom of the table, below the the last item. I can obviously drag a cell over the position of the last cell, but once I drag it below that last cell's area, the drag sort of cancels and the cell goes back to it's original location.

How can I drag an item to **below the last item**?

[image: Dragging to bottom snaps item back to original position]

I'm not doing anything unusual in my tables. This appears to be standard behavior.

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, itemsForBeginning session: UIDragSession, at indexPath: IndexPath) -> [UIDragItem] {
        if renamingIndexPath != nil { return [] }
        
        return [UIDragItem(itemProvider: NSItemProvider())]
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dropSessionDidUpdate session: UIDropSession, withDestinationIndexPath destinationIndexPath: IndexPath?) -> UITableViewDropProposal {
        if session.localDragSession != nil { // Drag originated from the same app.
            return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .move, intent: .insertAtDestinationIndexPath)
        }
        return UITableViewDropProposal(operation: .cancel, intent: .unspecified)
    }
    
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, performDropWith coordinator: UITableViewDropCoordinator) {
        let destinationIndexPath: IndexPath

        if let indexPath = coordinator.destinationIndexPath {
            destinationIndexPath = indexPath
        } else {
            let section = tableView.numberOfSections - 1
            let row = tableView.numberOfRows(inSection: section)
            destinationIndexPath = IndexPath(row: row, section: section)
        }
    }
    
    // Keeps the items inside the same app
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, dragSessionIsRestrictedToDraggingApplication session: UIDragSession) -> Bool {
        return true
    }
```

Comment: Were you able to fix it?

Comment: did you find a solution for this?

Comment: As of July 2022, no solution, but I have also not spent effort recently to try anything/research it.